# Updating Bag items in NHibernate Merge

Tags: c#, nhibernate, cascade

A little curiosity. I have a User object which contains a bag each of UserPhoto, UserMatchInterest, UserPreference objects. I have given each item in the bag a reference to the parent User and with nhibernate I have got the two way mapping sorted so that when you Create the user object for the first time, it automatically creates the UserPhoto, UserMatchInterest and UserPreference objects in the collection bags, setting the UserId to the parent User object, that works fine.

As an example, the UserPhoto table has a PhotoId PK column and a UserId FK column. The UserPhoto object has the PhotoId property and a User property (not UserId) and so rather than holding the UserId, it holds a reference to the parent and populates the DB column based on the Users PK.

The problem I have is when I want to update the User object all in one go. The rest of the User object updates fine, but when it comes to the photos, it creates new photos in the database. I can understand why, as they are not linked at all to the previous photo session objects which is acceptable as being an ASP.NET website I will be dealing with detached objects. But it leaves the old ones. So if you had photo ID 1 & 2, with UserId=1. After the update, you will have photos 1,2,3 & 4 with UserId=1. What I want is for photo 1 & 2 to be deleted and then insert 3 & 4 instead.

I have tried to retrieve them independently as a collection and delete them in the transaction first, but I get the message

```
Message = "deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)
```

Code to delete is as follows

```
// First delete existing photos, interests and preferences


       var photos = from row in repository.GetItemsAsQuery<UserPhoto>()
                     where row.User.UserId == user.UserId
                     select row;
        repository.DeleteItems(photos.ToList());

        var interests = from row in repository.GetItemsAsQuery<UserMatchInterest>()
                        where row.User.UserId == user.UserId
                        select row;
        repository.DeleteItems(interests.ToList());

        var preferences = from row in repository.GetItemsAsQuery<UserPreference>()
                          where row.User.UserId == user.UserId
                          select row;
        repository.DeleteItems(preferences.ToList());

        // Now update the user object and re-add the above linked items
        repository.UpdateItem(user);
```

The error is thrown on the repository.DeleteItems(interests.ToList()); line, the first delete passes fine - though it is all in a transaction.

My question is am I approaching this the right way to update an object in the DB which has bags of other objects it needs to update as well? I don't see any way to update existing photo objects without manually setting ID's - and the user may have replaced all photos or added/deleted anyway so it is probably cleaner to delete existing and re-add new, but how do I delete existing ones without getting this cascade error?

Answer (score 0):

from your description i envision the following classes

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; private set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public User Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

then the mapping would look like

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        HasMany(x => x.Photos)
            .AsSet()   // no duplicate entries, allows NH to optimise some things
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Component(c =>
            {
                c.ParentReference(x => x.Parent);
                c.Map(x => x.Name);
                c.Map(x => x.Data);
            });
    }
}
```

Note: the Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan will delete all children automaticly which are not part of the collection anymore